# Is "Info" an understood abbreviation for "Información"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, abreviaturas

I am working on an interface design in Spanish, and one of the pages on the interface is translated as "**Información**". This term is too long for the place it displays, so I'm wondering if "**Info**" would be a completely understood abbreviation for Spanish-only speakers?

Would it be clear that it refers to "Información"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly understandable.

To back my words up, you can see the attached image taken from *El Corte Inglés*'s website (See button marked with the red arrow).
*El Corte Inglés* is a very known shopping mall chain here in Spain.

[image: El Corte Inglés]

Comment: Exactly, and the `+Info` thingy is very much used to convey the "more information" meaning

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks! It seems to be the case in many languages (French, Italian, Portuguese, Indonesian...)

Comment: Feel free to rollback my changes, but when reading your post it was a little bit difficult for me to see what you meant because the first thing you see it the highlighted top right corner "**Info**rmación financiera", so I added a brief not pointing to the bottom green button, with the relevant info.

Comment: @Diego Yes, I was aware of that. Chrome highlighted all occurences of "Info" in the page, but I was in a hurry this morning and got no time to fix it. I've changed the image, removing the "Información financiera" label and including a red arrow. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 9):

The word *info* is not registered in the RAE's dictionary, but the RAE itself does not hesitate to use it [in their communications](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1108293975520235520):

> #RAEconsultas Las comillas inglesas no son incorrectas. Se recomienda usar en primera instancia las españolas (« »), reservando las inglesas (“ ”) y las simples (‘ ’), en este orden, para entrecomillar partes de un texto ya entrecomillado. Más info  en http://ow.ly/Uik630lowYH

Truth is that the word *info* is common and widely used as a shortened version of *información* in the Spanish language.

Comment: A "info" found in the DRAE itself! God job! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be clear that “Info” refers to Información.

One will frequently see the phrase “más info” on websites as well. It simply means “more info”, and can be replaced by other phrases such as ”leer más”.